# Should we have a PSA/Community bulletin to stop using Wubi now that it has been officially pulled from development releases?

Tags: discussion

I see lots of questions cropping up about Wubi limitations.  The thing is already dead and fated to just go away eventually.  Should new users see this in the community bulletin block on the landing page?

Comment: I'll change the accepted if that's what is supposed to happen, I just can't uncheck a mod answer without at least one other mod statement to the contrary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. I'll add it (adding it to my todo list).

Comment: It came back like the sequel of a horror slasher movie. http://askubuntu.com/a/330112/15811  :)

Comment: @Rinzwind - The "same unreliability" bit in that answer is cute.  The answer is dripping with venom, but I like it.  There really should be some completely off the fence on this one in the near-ish future.  The fact that it exists, doesn't necessarily mean that it's supported though, think alpha/beta.

Answer (score 20):

As long as we have a supported operating system WUBI should be supported, endorsed and advised (but with other options as being better) as a valid method of using Ubuntu.

Even the download page still gives the option to use it http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer :

> With Wubi, **our officially supported Ubuntu installer for Windows**, you can install and uninstall Ubuntu easily and safely. For 12.04 LTS only.
>
> Windows installer is not compatible with Windows 8 or UEFI firmware, and is not available for Ubuntu 13.04.

As long as that page exists I disagree on us stating WUBI should not be used anymore. The disclaimer above is more than enough.

Until April 2017 questions about WUBI are on-topic; a statement on the landing page will not stop those questions.

---

Update: wubi seems to be valid again for 13.04: https://askubuntu.com/a/330112/15811
( http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/wubi.exe )

Comment: I don't mean to stop the questions, just put out a flag to say "don't expect this to remain relevant forever...it's going away"

Comment: oh and I expect people that go to the download page to understand the limitations WUBI has. They are warned twice: once on the 1st page and a 2nd time when they click the link to the actual download. Should be more than enough :)

Comment: @Rinzwind trust me; it isn't.

Comment: I upvoted your answer btw because it is correct. I will still (not immediately) write up a community bulletin (hopefully with input from other mods) about it though.

Comment: @RolandiXor pessimist! :D

Answer (score -1):

I think we should and it should discuss the plan moving forward. It would be nice if some statement of the preferred alternative(s) were referenced or linked to.

Comment: That's a comment not really an answer.  I was just trying to get ahead of the next LTS coming out and a slew of questions on how to leapfrog upgrade in a no longer supported tool to try and eek more out something that is dead/dying.