# Do we, or do we not support wubi.exe?

Tags: discussion, support, scope, help-center

I have been wondering this for a while and would like to get a definitive answer.

We still get questions on `wubi` on the site, however, it is no longer developed and won't work on a modern Windows OS (8, 8.1, 10), so is it off topic or not?

What got me thinking was a [close vote on this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/720566/cant-install-application) as `off topic` ( I guess, based on comments by [@kos](https://askubuntu.com/users/380067/kos)) but the help does not mention `wubi` at all.

What are your opinions on this?

Comment: Related: [Wubi discussion (AGAIN) - Supported Here on Ask Ubuntu? (13.04 and later)](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7497/wubi-discussion-again-supported-here-on-ask-ubuntu-13-04-and-later)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think I made a mistake.

I've always seen questions about Wubi being closed as off-topic because of it being discontinued, and since that itself made sense I endorsed the same practice.

However reading [this post](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/7341/380067) I understand I overlooked an important point, which is that Wubi is still an option for some supported releases (specifically 12.04.x and 14.04.x).

So I removed my close vote and my comment on that question.

I think that as long as 12.04.x and 14.04.x are not EOL we should provide support for Wubi on 12.04.x and 14.04.x (unless on UEFI), as it is still a vaild method to install those releases.

After all if Ubiquity would be discontinued today we would still support installing supported releases which rely on it.

Comment: You make a great point here, I got the 12.04 and 14.04 iso and checked, wubi is gone from 14.04 but is still included in 12.04, so I guess it can stay for now based on this evidence, at least until 12.04 goes eol anyway, thanks. Don't know why this did not show as a duplicate of that link but at least we have the definitive answer I was looking for :)

Comment: @markkirby To my surprise, it's also included in the 14.04 ISO: http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ (this time I checked, to avoid further mistakes :))

Comment: @kos "unless on UEFI or on Windows 8+" should be "unless on UEFI" only. If you install Windows 8+ in old BIOS mode, it still works.

Comment: @ngng Fair point, Windows 8+ machines with a compatible bootloader should be supported, I should have included those. However [Wubi won't work on fresh Windows 8 installations](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) (and I suppose the same goes for fresh Windows 10 installations).

Comment: @kos here is a strange thing I noticed, not really relevant to this question but before I looked on an XUbuntu 14.04 ISO, no wubi, after reading your comment I check an Ubuntu 14.04 ISO and you are correct, it is there.

Comment: What are your sources for 14.04? wubi was deprecated with 13.04.

Comment: @markkirby I might be wrong but I think Wubi never supported flavours other than the default, that would explain it.

Comment: @Seth Here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/, also I mounted the 64-bit image for 14.04.3 and it was there, so I'm sure it's in the ISO.

Comment: I actually found some questions on this very topic, see this and its duplicates http://askubuntu.com/questions/522181/wubi-exe-is-not-in-xubuntu-14-04-disks-can-someone-help-me-install-xubuntu1404

Comment: @kos It was included through 14.10. They deprecated it but didn't pull it until 15.04. Hence so many wubi questions still.

Comment: @markkirby Only Xubuntu has dropped Wubi since 12.10. see [info at blog of bcbc](http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.ca/2012/10/tricking-wubi-installing-xubuntu.html)

Comment: @markkirby Ah I see. Never used Wubi other than once with 10.04 (I think), and I tried the normal release, so I didn't really know. Thanks.

Comment: @Seth Yes, what I meant we should support only 12.04.x and 14.04.x since other releases are off-topic anyway.

Comment: @kos then no. wubi is deprecated >=13.04, it's not worth the pain to make it work. 12.04 is OK however.

Comment: @Seth Wouldn't it be the same pain to make it work for 12.04.x or for 14.04.x though?

Comment: Theoretically no, @kos, since 12.04 and wubi were made to work together. Of course, now that it's 12.04.5 I'm not sure what all has changed.

Comment: @Seth Unless I'm overreading [this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/7596/380067) (last paragraph) I understand that Wubi is still fully supported (aside from on UEFI and on Windows 8+ with an incompatible bootloader) till the end of 2016, and the fact that they included it in the ISO to me strongly suggests that using it with 14.04.x would be supported. Or are there known issues with that?

Comment: @kos It is also possible to make a fresh install with Windows 8+ in old BIOS mode.  But the default mode is the UEFI mode if your BIOS supports UEFI (!) and Microsoft says that a pre-installed Windows 8+ must be installed in UEFI mode and BIOS must support UEFI, of course. So the difference between Windows 7 and Windows 8+ is the default mode and the rules of Microsoft for a pre-installed Windows.

Comment: @ngng So the bootloader mentioned in the Wubi page is specifically the bootloader installed when Windows is installed in UEFI mode? Bear with me but that page puts everything in the box and seems to suggest that Wubi won't work on a freshly installed Windows 8 on a vague "default" bootloader, without making a distinction between Windows installed in legacy mode and Windows installed in UEFI mode.

Comment: @kos Yes, exactly. Windows 8 default bootloader = Windows bootloader for UEFI. IMHO the description should be a simplification for Windows users. In most cases it is true.

Comment: @kos IMHo there is also another point why we should support Wubi. e.g.: If you installed Wubi for 12.04.5 in the past and you want 14.04. It is not necessary to install a new Wubi version. You can use an upgrade like other Ubuntu users, too. So it is also possible to use Ubuntu 15.10 installed by an old Wubi version. So I would say, we should not support a new install with Wubi since 14.10, but support an existing install, if the Ubuntu version has not reached its end of life. 14.10 is EOL, the Wubi version on 15.04 iso is for 14.10, there is no Wubi version on 15.10 iso.

Comment: @ngng I searched a bit and you seem to be right, installing Windows 8 in legacy mode seems to allow a functional installation of Wubi. I removed that bit. I too don't see downsides in supporting Ubuntu versions that were installed starting from a functional Wubi installation (as long as they're not EOL) so yeah, I'm going to agree with that too.

Comment: @kos Thx. The sad thing is that we think that Wubi is not off topic but the maintainers are not interested in releasing fixed Wubi versions which work in UEFI mode, too. I read [this post of  hakuna_matata](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2304243&p=13418221#post13418221) and I am deeply disappointed. I don't understand the maintainers because the Wubi versions I have tested really have worked.